# Scaling display for Mac OSX in VMWare

Tags: macos, mac, vmware-workstation, scaling, high-dpi

I'm running Mac OSX 10.10 under VMWare 12, my monitor is a 4K 27" display - so the text is tiny.

I opened System Preference -> Display -> Scaled, but the only option available is 3840 x 2160 (my 4K resolution).

Is there a tool / a way to scale Mac OSX under VMWare ?

Comment: i believe display settings can also be changed in the preferences menu of VMWare itself?

Comment: @pieter-jangoeman : no, at least for OSX. However found this Retina Display Manager tool which works well: https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple tools for this problem:

- Retina Display Manager (https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM): Free, with GUI.
- SwitchResX (http://www.madrau.com/) : not free, 15-day trial, lots of options
- cscreen: free, no GUI - install `homebrew` then run `brew cask install cscreen`

So far, I found RDM it's the best: it's free and offer a nice GUI to choose the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Display Menu / Display Menu Pro works for me, at least under OSX El.CAP 10.11

[Display Menu's menu ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjrsW.png) 
 You can also use System Preferences > Accessibility
 and under 'Zoom' enable either keyboard shortcuts or mouse. 
 I find(  under [ options... ] )
  ticking 'Only when the pointer reaches an edge' makes zoomed screens 
  much more usable.

the only corner-case issue I've noticed with this is that some X11 apps running under XQuartz seem to pick up the 'real', physical display resolution, rather than the dynamic, virtual 'zoomed' display resolution. Consequently fonts etc in these apps appear huge when zoomed with accessibility. I've not found any Xdefaults or otherwise way to affect this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Have you tried going to System Preferences under Display and switching the option from "Default for display" to "Scaled" ?